# Why won't the printing message print in my C# code?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am trying to print out the message "printing..." to the txtMessage.Text text box before the loop runs but it never does print to the text box before the loop runs. Any idea why?

```
else
            {
                txtMessage.Text = "Printing...";
                for (int i = numberCopies; i != 0; i--)
                {
                    int paper = Convert.ToInt32(lblPaperAmount.Text);
                    paper--;
                    if (paper == 480 || paper == 380 || paper == 400 || paper == 200)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("There is a paper Jam! Please remove the Jam and then hit the ok button to continue!", "Important Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                    }
                    lblPaperAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(lblPaperAmount.Text) - 1);
                    lblTonerAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(lblTonerAmount.Text) - 1);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                txtMessage.Text = "Job is completed!";
            }
```

Comment: Lol. You overwrote it yourself with the "completed!" message.

Comment: @Jk To expand on that, wherever you use `txtMessage.Text = ...`, you should change it to `txtMessage.Text += ...`, unless you want show *only* the new message

Comment: @JK. Yeah its fine to overwrite it after the for loop

Comment: @Rob Even if i add it before the if and else statement it still wont print before the for loop.

Comment: Winform does not update the UI thread in time - that is why Job is Completed is all you see.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1000);` is a bad idea on the UI thread.

Comment: @Blorgbeard What do you recommend me use then? I want to basically slow the rate of the for loop so it acts more like a printer :).

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` to do the printing logic with `ReportProgress` to update the form or send error messages back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a call to Refresh after setting the text. It's possible you're entering the loop quickly enough the refresh does not happen until you exit.

```
else
{
    txtMessage.Text = "Printing...";
    txtMessage.Refresh(); //force the control to redraw
    for (int i = numberCopies; i != 0; i--)
    {
        int paper = Convert.ToInt32(lblPaperAmount.Text);
        paper--;
        if (paper == 480 || paper == 380 || paper == 400 || paper == 200)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is a paper Jam! Please remove the Jam and then hit the ok button to continue!", "Important Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        }
        lblPaperAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(lblPaperAmount.Text) - 1);
        lblTonerAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(lblTonerAmount.Text) - 1);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    txtMessage.Text = "Job is completed!";
}
```

Comment: You'll notice that your UI will still be frozen while "printing" though. Hit print and try to move or resize the form.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running in a single thread. You should set your text to "Printing..." then spin off a new thread to do your paper jam for loop.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661561/102526) question and the top 3 answers.